# Fontconfig warning: "msfonts-rules.conf", line 23:

Tags: 12.10, fonts

How can I fix this message:

```
Fontconfig warning: "msfonts-rules.conf", line 23: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the /etc/fonts/msfonts-rules.conf file

Find the section saying:

```
<match target="font">
        <test name="family">
            <string>Andale mono</string>
            <string>Arial</string>
            ...
</match>
```

Inside the  tag there is a bunch of Andale Mono etc tags. These need to be wrapped inside their own  tag. So for example

```
<match target="font">
    <test name="family">
        <string>Andale Mono</string>
    </test>
    <test name="family">
        <string>Arial</string>
    </test>
    ...
</match>
```

See this thread for more detailed how to:
[Ubuntu forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2038324&page=2&p=12159762#post12159762)